# layout xml conditional of $_request params

Tags: magento, layout

I understand it's in theory possible to use system config to determine the layout of a page (with the `ifconfig` option), is it possible to do something similar with variables passed by get or post? Or a cookie value for that matter?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What is the use case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible in standard Magento.

Depending on your use case there are some ways:

1. Implement an own XML attribute, for example `<action method="foo" ifrequestvar="...">` The  modle [Aoe_LayoutConditions](https://github.com/fbrnc/Aoe_LayoutConditions) could give you a starting point:
2. Add an own layout handle. i.e. you check your condition that should be meet in normal PHP code (that works if the condition, i.e. the value of your `$_REQUEST` var is always the same) and then you can use this layout handle in the layout XML. You can add layout handles in an observer as shown in [N98_CustomLayoutHandles](https://github.com/netz98/N98_CustomLayoutHandles/blob/master/src/app/code/community/N98/CustomLayoutHandles/Model/Observer.php).

Comment: Thanks Alex, went for the first option and am just heavily modifying it.